# Can't connect to meteor backend from react native app at android device

Tags: android, meteor, websocket, react-native

I have a meteor webapp and I need to connect to its backend from react native app. I set up sdk, connected my android device and run `react-native start` and `react-native run-android`, app gets loaded and client side works, except connection to meteor. I'm using this package https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-meteor and trying to connect to my locally running meteor backend with `Meteor.connect`, using `ws://192.168.xxx.xx.x` (my local ip address) but it doesn't connect. 
I've checked iptables and they seem to be clean. What could prevent that connection? What else could I try or check? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Did you use adb reverse command to connect to localhost from android device?

Comment: @TristanTzara, I have the exact same setup as you and it worked. Try running `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` on the command line. If you are still having trouble, check out this link if you haven't already: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-android.html. Oh, and just an observation, I didn't even run the `react-native start`command. Just the `react-native run-android`one. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that for the android emulator, you have to use a specific IP which it maps to localhost instead of localhost:

`ws://10.0.2.2:3000/websocket` instead of `ws://localhost:3000/websocket`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated sample repo here https://github.com/spencercarli/react-native-meteor-boilerplate

Be sure that meteor application is running and allow the port if you have firewall. Use your machine IP and connect in the same Access Point. Please follow the structure above which is created by spencercarli.

Answer (score 0):

For Android connection to meteor server you have to check your ip of the machine where your meteor server is running you can do this by running commmand ifconfig (Linux Ubuntu) then use this ip in your web socket URL ws://IP:Meteorserverport/websocket and your android device must be connected to internet using same network that you machine is connected with eg WIFI Only then it will run. Note: for production app this is not required.